Is it possible to use Gcc 11 and G++ 11 in Ubuntu 16.04?
I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, and I just could update my Gcc and G++ compilers up to 9.4.0 version, but I need to use Gcc and G++ 11. How could I do that?
I expect to solve the previous issue about updating or installing manually gcc and g++ 11

I don't know all  your requirements but one possibility is to install Docker and run Ubuntu 16.04 through  there, compiling gcc-11 from source.
Using Dockerfile:
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt update && \
    apt install build-essential software-properties-common wget && \
    wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-11.2.0/gcc-11.2.0.tar.gz && \
    tar -xf gcc-11.2.0.tar.gz && \
    cd gcc-11.2.0 && \
    ./configure --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib && \
    make -j$(nproc) && \
    make install

Assuming that does not error, run the image interactively using the -it flag  and check if gcc is installed:
gcc --version

If that works, then you'd need to complete writing the Dockerfile yourself to reproduce whatever you were doing.
I can only offer you this as a possible starting point because compiling gcc from source takes a while.
